# Seeking alternative to deprecated Min in Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I've been trying to run an old model built on 9.3 within 10.6 and I've run into the following error:

> NameError: name 'Min' is not defined

I believe the Min function was removed after 10.0 (?) but I can't work out how to update this equation:

```
Min(Mod("%Dist%",5), %D0%+%R0%+%DA%+%RA%+%DB%+%RB%)
```

Dist is a Euclidean Distance Raster, the other Variables are numbers.

Comment: Perhaps try cell statistics.

Answer (score 2):

The [`CellStatistics`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) function/tool has replaced [`Min`](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=min) in ArcGIS 10x (actually, it was only available in map algebra tools and raster calculator, cell statistics was available for scripting).

Usage:

```
CellStatistics (in_rasters_or_constants, {statistics_type}, {ignore_nodata})
```

Try:

```
CellStatistics([Mod("Dist",5), D0+R0+DA+RA+DB+RB], 'MINIMUM')
```